# What did it use to mean for a kohen to get a second aliyah?

Tags: torah-reading, kohen-priest, torah-service

If there is no *levi* present in the synagogue, the second *aliyah* is given to the *kohen* who received the first *aliyah*. (Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 135:8)

Now, originally only the first and last *olim* recited the blessings preceding and following the reading, respectively. All other *olim* recited no blessings at all, and simply continued reading from where the previous *oleh* left off. (Megillah 21b)

That being the case, where no *levi* was present, how would one differentiate between the *kohen*'s first and second readings? Did there use to be a different practice that was followed in such a situation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tosfot ([Gittin 59b](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=19&daf=59b)) answers (based on a similar case in Tosefta Megilla 3:6) that to distinguish the two sections, the kohen would go sit down back in his seat and then stand up again and go up to the Torah.